# All my databases are not showing up in web2py appadmin/index

Tags: web2py

All my databases in appadmin/index have disappeared including the default dabases of  **db.auth_user**, **db.auth_group**, **db.auth_membership**, **db.auth_permission**, **db.auth_event**, **db.auth_cas**, there is nothing.

When i click the insert link in the Edit Application page under the *appadmin.py* controller I get redirected to the *appadmin/index* page and have the invalid request error message pop up, i don't know why that is happening. But i am still able to save information through the views, i am also able to access previously saved information on the client side, this is an indication that the database & its tables still exist i just cant see them from the appadmin/index page. How can i get back my tables to be visible again in appadmin/index and what could be the reason why they disappeared in the first place?

I am using **web2py 2.17.2** but i have tried to install this app on version 2.18.5 but it refused to install

Below are the tables for my app:

```
db.define_table('services',
                Field('service_name', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                format='%(service_name)s', migrate=False, fake_migrate=True)

db.define_table('tlamelo',
                Field('leina_la_tlamelo', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                format='%(leina_la_tlamelo)s', migrate=False, fake_migrate=True)

db.define_table('product',
                Field('product_name', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                format='%(product_name)s', migrate=False, fake_migrate=True)

db.define_table('locations',
                Field('name'),
                format='%(name)s')
def name_of(location): return '%(name)s' % location

db.define_table('business',
                Field('logo', 'upload'),
                Field('company_name', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('services', 'reference services'),
                #Field('tlamelo', 'reference tlamelo'),
                Field('product', 'reference product'),
                Field('tel', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('email', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('fax', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('cell', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('facebook', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('twitter', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('website', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('postal_address', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('place', 'reference locations'),
                Field('located_at', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()))

import datetime
db.define_table('black_market2',
                Field('regCode', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('fullNames', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('id_number', 'integer', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('contactNumber', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                #Field('place', 'reference locations'),
                Field('geographical_place', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('located_at', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('product', unique=True, requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('model', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('productionYear', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('productSerialNumber', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('offerPrice', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                #Field('expiry_date', 'date', default=request.now, writable=False),
                format='%(product)s', migrate=False, fake_migrate=True)
db.black_market2.product.requires=IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, 'black_market2.product')

db.define_table('regKeys',
                Field('regKey', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()), migrate=False, fake_migrate=True)

db.define_table('house_owner',
                Field('Surname'),
                Field('Name'),
                Field('Cell_Number'),
                Field('description', 'text'),
                Field('located_at'),
                Field('amount'),
                format="%(Name)s %(Surname)s", migrate=False, fake_migrate=True
               )
#def name_of(name): return "%(Name)s %(Surname)s" % name

db.define_table('house',
                Field('house_owner', 'reference house_owner'),
                #Field('description','text'),
                Field('title'),
                #Field('expiration_date', 'date', default=request.now, writable=False),
                Field('image', 'upload'), migrate=False, fake_migrate=True)

db.define_table('organization',
                Field('logo', 'upload'),
                Field('name'),
                Field('contacts'),
                format='%(name)s')

db.define_table('pdfs',
                Field('organization', 'reference organization'),
                Field('Form_Name'),
                Field('fileS','upload',uploadfolder=request.folder+'static/pdfs'), migrate=False, fake_migrate=True)

db.define_table('cartegories',
                Field('name'),
                format='%(name)s')

db.define_table('jobListings',
                Field('logo', 'upload'),
                Field('company'),
                Field('cartegory'),
                Field('post'),
                Field('post_description', 'text'),
                Field('expiry_date', 'date'))

db.define_table('governmentTenders',
                Field('logo', 'upload'),
                Field('company'),
                Field('cartegory'),
                Field('post'),
                Field('post_description', 'text'),
                Field('expiry_date', 'date'))

db.define_table('privateTenders',
                Field('logo', 'upload'),
                Field('company'),
                Field('cartegory'),
                Field('post'),
                Field('post_description', 'text'),
                Field('expiry_date', 'date'))
```

My appadmin/index page should be showing all my databases and their tables including the default databases. Please help me figure out what i am doing or have done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out why my databases disappeared, i had this line of code in my CSS file

```
.tab-content{
            display: none;
            background: #ededed;
            padding: 15px;
            border: solid 1px black;
            border-radius:10px;
        }
```

The `display: none;` line caused the databases to disappear because they are held inside a tab in the appadmin/index page. I changed the class name from `.tab-content` to something else and my databases re-appeared.